# One Jenkinsfile for multiples repositories

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to have 1 main repository with some common configurations to be used:

```
Common
   ---> jenkinsfile
   ---> x.json
   ---> config.json
```

I would like to have different teams to be able to use that common repo and just create their own repos with their specific additional code:

```
Team1 repo
  sub1/
  --->x.json
  --->config.json
  sub2/
  --->x.json
  --->config.json

Team2 repo
  --->x.json
  --->config.json
```

Is there a possibility to have this centralized Jenkinsfile to be used by the different teams without explicitly putting it in their respective repositories?

thank you.

Comment: You can configure the Jenkins Pipeline job to retrieve the `Jenkinsfile` from a specific repo. Is that option not available in your Jenkins installation?

Comment: As you tagged this GitHub please confirm whether you want to use an Organization Folder to generate your jobs or you intend to configue the job for each repositories manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the exact capabilities Jenkins [Shared Libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/10/02/pipeline-templates-with-shared-libraries/) gives you.

[Blog](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/10/21/a-sustainable-pattern-with-shared-library/),

[Docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).

Comment: While pages behind links tends to be unavailable, you should paste in relevant thing here. So the content keeps available for future. Also  link only answers does not meet [so] guilelines.

Comment: Was gonna make it comment, was gonna maybe paste an example, then figured Q does not have enough detail and OP can [do some basic research](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (RTFM) if pointed in the right direction.

Comment: And while links may become unavailable, copy/pasting into S/O inevitably leads to duplicated that becomes stale and outdated. Do you go update old answers when they become sstale or outdated?

Comment: As as matter of fact, new answers will be added to old questions. Never mind, if you don't want to modify your questions, is it up to you. My comment was just I a hint. for myself I copied relevant examples and snippet from targeted webpage, because SO want to be an archive for code solutions.

Comment: When S/O [find a solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302/introducing-outdated-answers-project) and implement it instead of [playing w/UI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418851/updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows-currently-in-a-b-testing) I'll reconsider my approach. Thx.